# How to hide and/or combine print() and input() outputs?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm new to Python and Jupiter Lab/Notebook.  I'm starting to create functions that include a lot of user input() and print().  The problem is, with how they are displayed, it soon turns into two lists growing apart - a short example is shown below.

```
input('1 Yes or No: ')
print('2 Going Along.')
input('3 Yes or No: ')
print('4 Going Along.')
input('5 Yes or No: ')
print('6 Going Along.')
input('7 Yes or No: ')
print('8 Going Along.')
```

Results in:

```
1 Yes or No: Yes
 2 Going Along.
 4 Going Along.
 6 Going Along.
 8 Going Along.
3 Yes or No: No
5 Yes or No: Maybe
7 Yes or No: Not Sure
```

I have two questions.
(1) Is there a way to hide input() lines after they have been entered?
(2) Is there a way to display these lines in the order they are executed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're saying statements 4, 6, and 8 execute before 3, 5, and 7? I'm unable to reproduce this behavior in any of my environments

Comment: I cant seem to upload my screenshot, but the end result looks exactly as I've posted.  They execute in the order they are numbered, but they display separately as I've shown - which I do not like.

Comment: Here is the screenshot:  https://ibb.co/JrCC4Gn

Answer (score 0):

While i cannot reproduce your behaviour of line execution, i tried to write an input function, that removes itself after the user input

```
import sys
import msvcrt

def vanishing_input(msg):
    sys.stdout.write(msg)
    user_input = ''
    while True:
        x = msvcrt.getch().decode("utf-8")
        if x == '\r':
            break
        sys.stdout.write(x)
        user_input += x

    print("\r" + " " * (len(msg) + len(user_input)) + "\r", end='')
    return user_input
```

It is exactly used like the normal input.

```
vanishing_input('1 Yes or No: ')
print('2 Going Along.')
```

Currently there are some problems with moving the cursor or removing a character, but i think you can improve this wierd occurrences yourself.

Comment: Thanks Saritus, but see this screenshot:   ibb.co/JrCC4Gn